# change viewport layout

Tags: interface

Yohoo!:)

As a 20 + years user of kind of every cad app on earth i am super amazed i have to ask this question!

How do i change the viewport layout? Like, in any way at all..

I manage to add more duplicate windows(why is it even possible to do that?) and then they cant be removed. I cant move any toolbars to anywhere.

Heeeeeeeeeeellllllllppppppppppp :)

[image]

Comment: did you try to "right click" on the toolbars you want to move? there should be "flip to bottom" or "flip to top".

Comment: Hi. Please only ask one question at a time. You are welcome to ask multiple questions but as separate posts. All the customisations you want seem like separate questions to me (some of which have already been answered). For example, this should help with closing extra 3D views: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/129387/how-to-close-windows-in-2-8 . Thanks.

Comment: My sympathies.. I remember it driving me nuts, years ago, but now I don't notice it. https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/interface/window_system/areas.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it can be confusing, so here we go :)

1. Flip the header - *Right click on header > Flip to top*
2. Remove Status Bar - *Window > ✓ Show status bar*
3. Use current layout for new files - *File > Defaults > Save startup file*

*Flip the header*

[image]

*Remove status bar* - pretty useful to keep, shows total/selected geometry and available shortcuts

[image]

Comment: thank you so much! you made my day!:)

Comment: Happy to help :). You can mark the answer as accepted **✓**, for other confused newcomers.