# interface mess (again)

Tags: interface

blender is amazing i have to say to begin with!!! but some of the ux design is like whaaaaatt:)

so once again my interface got messed up and i cant get it to how it was before..

how can i get rid of all the tabs/windows/duplicates there is no "close" option anywhere no matter where or how i click. (well i have to admit i didnt try every possible pixel on the screen)

can blender pleeeeeease add standard/recogniceable buttons for moving these tabs around/closing them?

thanks!

[image]

Comment: Does [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/129388/86891) help ?

Answer (score 0):

The way I like to use to close windows is right click the little border between two, and then press Join. You will know when you can right click as you hover over the border and your mouse becomes a partition. Then click one of the two windows that you want to join and they both become one.

The window you click will turn into part of the one you didn't click, merging into one.

In my opinion, this is much better because it allows you to preserve the state of one window.

If you want to open a window again, just move your mouse to a corner until it becomes a crosshair, and drag it to the correct size. Hope this helps!