# I don't know how to reset the workspace

Tags: customization, workspaces

I messed up my workspace, here is how i want my workspace to look when i select uv mapping for example:
[image]

but this is how it looks like on my screen:

[image]

Comment: You could do a factory reset: File > Defaults > Load Factory Settings.

Comment: Read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/129387/how-to-close-windows-in-2-8?