# Problem while resizing tabs

Tags: animation

[image]

alright so today I was resizing the encircled tab but now when i try to resize it again its linked with the preferences tab, how do I unlink them?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This post helped me a lot with viewport controls https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/165915/110840